# How to use sub fields in Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Javascript sdk from the Facebook Graph API.
When posting a link using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed/#publish) I can simply do

```
"link" : "http://mylink.com"
```

and the link gets posted. Now to change the name of that link to something else I need to use the `name` sub-field. What is the proper way to send a sub-field? I tried,

```
"link" : ["http://mylink.com",
{
      "name": "here"
}]
```

But this is wrong.

EDIT:
This is what I am trying now.

```
FB.api(
         "/me/feed",
         "POST",
         {
             "message": "My message ",
             "link" : "http://mylink.com?name=here&caption=caption"
         },
         function (response) {
           if (response && !response.error) {
               /* handle the result */
                console.log("Posted to facebook");
           }
           else
              console.log(response);
    });
```

But this just shows the link with no custom name or caption.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer Including 'facebook-graph-api' tag prevents my question from being viewed at all. My view count doesn't increase, hence I changed it to just js.

Comment: Please post actual code examples of what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no problems when issuing the following call:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
    link    : 'http://www.reddit.com/',
    caption : 'caption',
    message : 'message',
    name    : 'name'
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

You can check out all the available fields here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post

Your app needs the `publish_actions` permission in order to make these calls.

Comment: You should have made it clear in your question that your using the JS SDK, but yes, it should work for that as well

Comment: That's the reason I tagged Javascript and not anything else. Anyways, I'll include that.

Comment: Post your javascript SDK calls in your question, try to include all the fields I have included in my example.